# Filter 2 ui-grids based on row selection from the other (in a component, unsure of scope)

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have 2 ui-grids. When the user selects a row from one, it should apply a filter to the other. Here's my code:

```
angular.module("myApp").component("viewcomponent", {
    templateUrl: "html/View.html",
    controllerAs: "c",
    controller: ['$filter', 'uiGridConstants', View_Controller]
})
function View_Controller($filter, uiGridConstants) {
    var c = this

    c.firstGrid = {
        enableRowSelection: true, 
        columnDefs: [{field: "id"},{field: "name"}],
        enableFiltering: true,
        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
            c.firstGridApi = gridApi
            gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged(null, function(row){
                c.secondGrid.columnDefs[0].filter = row.entity.id
            })
        }
    }

    c.secondGrid = {
        enableRowSelection: true, 
        columnDefs: [{field: "id"},{field: "name"}],
        enableFiltering: true,
        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
            c.secondGridApi = gridApi
            gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged(null, function(row){
                c.firstGrid.columnDefs[0].filter = row.entity.id
            })
        }
    }
}
```

When I select a row in one nothing happens in the other.

### What am I missing?

---

Things I've tried:

- `c.firstGridApi.core.refresh()` after the filter is applied.
- `c.firstGridApi.grid.clearAllFilters()` before the filter is applied.
- `c.firstGrid.columnDefs[0].filter[0] = row.entity.id`, but this produces an error:

  > `TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`
- passing in the scope, `c`, to the `rowSelectionChanged` event. However I'm not sure if this is the scope because it produces an error:

  > `asked to listen on selection.on.rowSelectionChanged but scope wasn't passed in the input parameters.` Could this be the reason the grids won't bind together?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after digging through the console and the secondGridApi, I found that I need to use

```
c.secondGridApi.grid.columns[0].filters
```

Not

```
c.secondGrid.columnDefs[0].filter
```

However this seems to work only with one filter. When I add more, I think it tries to find something with all those things in one cell. I will update this if I figure that out.